# Rails transaction not rolling back

Tags: activerecord, transactions, ruby-on-rails-4

Why wouldn't this transaction rollback if even one create! fails?
It's in a controller if that makes any difference.

```
def process_photos(photos)
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    begin
      photos.each do |photo|
        Photo.create!(creator_user: @user, buyer: @buyer, url: photo['url'])
      end
    rescue
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end
end
```

I'm explicitly sending an array with some bad records. The good ones are getting created and the bad ones aren't but I need the whole thing to rollback if even one fails.

Here's my rspec test (passing a json array of photos) and it's incrementing.

```
expect { post :create, json }.not_to change(Photo, :count)
```

Comment: Something seems wrong with your nested @kjs3. Specifically the `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do` doesn't seem to have a matching `end`.

Comment: Copy fail. It is nested right. Fixed.

Comment: It looks like this is an rspec issue. The transaction appears to be rolling back when I post with curl.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This was just a testing issue with rspec because you're already executing in a transaction in the test. It's the same nested transaction issue discussed [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html).
In order to get the test to work you need to add…

```
requires_new: true
```

to the transaction call.

This fixed the test.

```
def process_photos(photos)
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction(requires_new: true) do
    begin
      photos.each do |photo|
        Photo.create!(creator_user: @user, buyer: @buyer, url: photo['url'])
      end
    rescue
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end
end
```

**Important:** Rollbacks will only work if your database engine supports them! For example MySQL with MyISAM doesn't support transactions, while MySQL with Inno DB does support them.

Answer (score 0):

This works as well, without the need to propagate the ActiveRecord::Rollback exception.

```
def process_photos(photos)
  begin
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      photos.each do |photo|
        Photo.create!(creator_user: @user, buyer: @buyer, url: photo['url'])
      end
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    puts 'Transaction failed'
  end
end
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to put begin outside the block like this

```
def process_photos(photos)
 begin
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
          photos.each do |photo|
            Photo.create!(creator_user: @user, buyer: @buyer, url: photo['url'])
          end
        rescue
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
        end
      end
    end
```